# Learn Python the Hard Way, Exercise 15

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve exercise 15's extra credit questions of Zed Shaw's Learn Python the Hard Way but I've ran into a problem.  The code is as follows:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()
print "I'll also ask you to type it again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)
print txt_again.read()

print txt_again.read()
```

I understand all the code that has been used, but extra credit question 7 asks:

> Startup `python` again and use `open` from the prompt. Notice how you can open files and run `read` on them right there?

I've tried inputting everything I could think of in terminal (on a mac) after first starting up python with the 'python' command, but I can't get the code to run. What should I be doing to get this piece of code to run from the prompt?

Comment: What excatly is "everything I could think of"? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I just started with `open(xyz.txt)` or `xyz.txt.read()` and I  would get _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ex15_sample' is not defined_ . Or I'd start with `from sys import argv` to import the argv module as I would in the script. As I am a beginner I still don't really understand how running code from the prompt differs from running it from a script.

Comment: Im doing this example right now, but when it reads my text file back I only get the last line. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I still don't get the answer to this extra credit question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Zed doesn't say to run *this* particular piece of code from within Python. Obviously, that code is getting the `filename` value from the parameters you used to invoke the script, and if you're just starting up the Python shell, you haven't used any parameters.

If you did:

```
filename = 'myfilename.txt'
txt = open(filename)
```

then it would work.

Answer (score 2):

> I just started with open(xyz.txt)

Well, yes, of course that isn't going to work, because you don't have a variable `xyz`, and even if you did, it wouldn't have an attribute `txt`. Since it's a file name, you want a **string** "xyz.txt", which you create by putting it in quotes: `'xyz.txt'`. Notice that Python treats single and double quotes more or less the same; unlike in languages like C++ and Java, there is not a separate data type for individual characters - they're just length-1 strings.

Comment: I was looking for explanation about those quotes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just like in this transcript (I've added blank lines to aid readability):

```
pax:~$ python 
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> xyz = open ("minimal_main.c")

>>> print xyz.read()
int main (void) {
    return 0;
}

>>> xyz.close()

>>> <CTRL-D>

pax:~$ _
```

All it's showing you is that you don't *need* a script in order to run Python commands, the command line interface can be used in much the same way.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that I should just skip the importing of the argv module when running from prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`print open('ex15_sample.txt').read()`

After running python in terminal, we'll use `open('filename.txt')` to open the file and using the dot operator we can apply the `read()` function directly on it.

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!

Comment: @Deep I basically clubbed opening and reading the file together. After running python in terminal, we'll use `open('filename.txt')` to open the file and using the dot operator we can apply the `read()` function directly on it. If you want you can do the two separately as is mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @AS Please [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42901144/edit) and include this information.

Answer (score -1):

After running Python in terminal,

```
abc = open ("ex15_sample.txt")
print abc.read()
```

That should do.